# New way of getting Unity PlayerMovement?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

Recently, i've been making a game with unity with C#. I've got a kind of a problem because i tried to make a collision script, and when i try to get the playermovement, it wont work, and it wont find "PlayerMovement"

```
public PlayerMovement movement;
```

My full class file:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour {

  public PlayerMovement movement;

  void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo)
  {
     if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
     {
       movement.enabled = false;
     }
  }

}
```

The error message is:

`error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PlayerMovement' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: You need to provide more information about it. How are you trying to get the playermovement?

Comment: I'm just trying to get the playermovement of the player so i can check if it collidies with something or not.

Comment: What error does it displays exactly? And how are you trying using playermovement

Comment: @slipz i mean like this: https://i.postimg.cc/x85hrFq2/screenshot-843.png

Comment: i just want to get it so i can disable my player's movement.

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/XJ0zr0CW/screenshot-844.png This is the error i am getting

Comment: How do you implement your PlayerMovement class?

Comment: uh?? there is "using UnityEngine" for it ._.

Comment: Are you sure that UnityEngine implements PlayerMovement? I never saw UnityEngine implementing such class, i gave it a little Google and still haven't found it...

Comment: Uhh not really sure, i cant find anywhere how to get that thing :\

Comment: Yes, that is your problem. I am almost sure that UnityEngine does not implements such class.

Comment: The error you are getting means that Unity understands that you are trying to use the PlayerMovement class, however it cannot find its implementation. Supposing that script is to provide movement to you character, you have a lot of other pre-built scripts to achieve that

Comment: Then how do i achieve that?

Comment: I will post it has an answer for you to close the post explaining how you can achieve that

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't have `PlayerMovement` class implemented.
You can implement your player movement using, for example, a `RigidBody` component, capture user keypresses (or any other inputs), and applying forces or changing `transform.position`.

Other solution is to use the available scripts that Unity already implements. If you want to add movement to a game character there is `CharacterController`, [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html) is the Unity documentation for this class.

To use it, you still have to implement a script to capture user's input (keypresses or whatever you want) and you can user the function `CharacterController.Move(Vector3 motion)`, where `Vector3 motion` is a direction vector, to move your GameObject. There are tons of tutorials online where you can find more about `CharacterController` or how to move an object in Unity.